# Python dictionary has json in it. How do I convert that dictionary to json?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have this dictionary (or so type() tells me):

```
{'uploadedby': 'fred', 
 'return_url': '', 
 'id': '2200', 
 'question_json': '{"ops":[{"insert":"What metal is responsible for a Vulcan\'s green blood?\\n"}]}'}
```

When I use json.dumps on it, I get this:

```
{"uploadedby": "fred", 
 "return_url": "", 
 "id": "2200", 
 "question_json": "{\"ops\":[{\"insert\":\"What metal is responsible for a Vulcan's green blood?\\n\"}]}", "question": "What metal is responsible for a Vulcan's green blood?\r\n"}
```

I don't want all the escaping that's going on.  Is there something I can do to correct this?

Comment: Turn the JSON into a dictionary first with json.loads. json.dumps just sees a string, it can't know you intend something special with it.

Comment: The first item is a dictionary, according to the code I'm modifying and type().  Is type() misleading me?

Comment: Specifically if the original is `mydict`, run `json.loads(mydict['question_json'])` to first convert that JSON string to a dict, then convert the whole thing to a string with `json.dumps(mydict)`. This may not remove all of the escape characters, like the new line char, but you will be working with a dict now and not a string.

Comment: The item is a dictionary, but the value of mydict['question_json'] is a string (that we know happens to contain JSON). If you do mydict['question_json'] = json.loads(mydict['question_json']) first then it will also be a dictionary.

Comment: RemcoGerlich: You should post that as an answer. because that was it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following to convert `question_json` into a python dict, and then dump the entire dict:

```
test = {'uploadedby': 'fred', 
 'return_url': '', 
 'id': '2200', 
 'question_json': '{"ops":[{"insert":"What metal is responsible for a Vulcan\'s green blood?\\n"}]}'}

json.dumps(
    {k: json.loads(v) if k == 'question_json' else v for k,v in test.items()}
    )

'{"question_json": {"ops": [{"insert": "What metal is responsible for a Vulcan\'s green blood?\\n"}]}, "uploadedby": "fred", "return_url": "", "id": "2200"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, which has the added benefit of not needing to specify which key contains the offending value. Here we're checking to see if we can effectively load a JSON string from any of the key-value pairs and leaving them alone if that fails.

```py
import json

mydict = {'uploadedby': 'fred', 
 'return_url': '', 
 'id': '2200', 
 'question_json': '{"ops":[{"insert":"What metal is responsible for a Vulcan\'s green blood?\\n"}]}'}

for key in mydict:
    try:
        mydict[key] = json.loads(mydict[key])
    except:
        pass
```

Now when we do a `json.dumps(mydict)`, the offending key is fixed and others are as they were:

```py
{'uploadedby': 'fred',
 'return_url': '',
 'id': 2200,
 'question_json': {'ops': [{'insert': "What metal is responsible for a Vulcan's green blood?\n"}]}}
```

Note that the `id` value has been converted to an `int`, which may or may not be your intent. It's hard to tell from the original question.